# RVM to rbenv causes javascript issues

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using RVM, and have migrated to rbenv as suggested by someone attempting to help me to deploy my app using capistrano.

After doing this migration my entire rails app is messed up.

A couple of examples of what worked perfectly before, but now is not working:

1) Routes: the signout button tries to use a GET HTTP verb instead of a DELETE, even though a delete is specified in the routes and the actual link_to line of the code.

2) Gems: My best_in_place gem and rickshaw gems are no longer working

3) I get two javascript errors
Error 1)

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
(in /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-   2ae0a9e09bf9/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js.coffee:2)
```

Error 2)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

Again, none of these problems previously existed, so I am hoping I am just overlooking an easy fix.

I am using rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0-p451.I encounter the same errors on my EC2 instance as I do on my local host (Mac mavericks OS).

Running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

yields the same javascript error

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
(in /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-  2ae0a9e09bf9/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js.coffee:2)
```

Comment: What happens when you run `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Same error for the jquery.iu.datepicker, I have edited the post to note that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your Gemfile

gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
Run bundle update, and it should work.